# QGIS Tapered rivers for entire landmass

Tags: qgis, style, rivers

I have a huge river network on my hands (see screen capture below), and would like to style its vector lines to get tapered rivers.

Some tutorials out there explain how to taper rivers (see links below), but they only deal with single albeit complex rivers. I have the river network for an entire landmass to deal with, and can't see myself dealing with each river network on its own.

So far, applying the techniques described in the tutorials below has not led to anything but failure: the rivers remain untapered.

My question would therefore be, can tapered rivers be created for multiple large river networks?

Tapered rivers tutorial sample:

**Better river styles with tapered lines** https://anitagraser.com/2017/04/17/better-river-styles-with-tapered-lines/

**Improved tapered rivers in QGIS** https://mirrodriguezlombardo.com/rios-afilados-qgis-en.html

**Style rivers with tapered lines using QGIS** https://youtu.be/BHPrlhsVtvw

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you saying you have multiple layers? Can you merge them?

Comment: Do rivers have an attribute that can be used for line width?

Comment: I only have one vector layer (see added screen capture above) for the rivers. I derived them from a raster layer via "GRASS r.to.vect". I can also successfuly apply the Vector Geoprocessing tool "Dissolve" to that vector layer. But in the end, I can't get anything tapered ... because, it seems, of the incredible large number of river networks I have to work with.

Comment: If you dissolved it have you turned it into one big multiline feature? Maybe that is why it doesnt work. Split it at the intersections

Comment: Sorry. Are you suggesting that the river network should be made of individual vector lines, or that it shouldn't? See screen capture above: before the "Dissolved" tool has been applied, I can select single river branches. Once the "Dissolve" tool has been applied, all rivers are considered to be a single vector.

Comment: I have not read the tutorials but I would think so. So if you have dissolved the layer into one feature you need to split them at junctions

Comment: `Multipart to single parts` probably does the job if you have everything as a single vector feature.